# How does rolify keep track of roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Rolify has a join table called user_roles that keeps track of all the relationships:

```
user_id role_id
```

But here's what's weird. When I **empty this table of all data each user still has its role remembered.**

I'm trying to manipulate the database in my specs, and it's impossible because of this spookiness.

Look at this from the console:

```
user = User.save
irb(main):022:0> user.roles # nothing weird, I have a before filter to make every new user a guest
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 1, name: "guest", resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57", updated_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57">]>
irb(main):023:0> UsersRole.all.each do |role| puts role.inspect end
=> [#<UsersRole user_id: 2, role_id: 1, id: 4>, #<UsersRole user_id: 2, role_id: 1, id: 5>]
irb(main):024:0> UsersRole.all.each do |role| role.delete end
=> [] # completely empty!
irb(main):026:0> user.roles # no way should this get anything
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 1, name: "guest", resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57", updated_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57">]>
```

I'd really appreciate some help into why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

you should reload your object after deleting the roles. rails caches association.

```
user = User.save
irb(main):022:0> user.roles
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 1, name: "guest", resource_id: nil, resource_type: nil, created_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57", updated_at: "2014-08-17 10:04:57">]>
irb(main):023:0> UsersRole.all.each do |role| puts role.inspect end
=> [#<UsersRole user_id: 2, role_id: 1, id: 4>, #<UsersRole user_id: 2, role_id: 1, id: 5>]
irb(main):024:0> UsersRole.all.each do |role| role.delete end
=> [] # completely empty!
irb(main):026:0> user.reload.roles
```